# Is this a sign of a memory leak in my Android app?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Is this a sign of a memory leak in my Android app?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a sign that dalvik's garbage collector works well preventing your app from memory leaks.

Comment: Ánd that you are doing any sort of memory intensive work (e.g. using the Camera) which requires the garbage collector to jump in frequently, because the VM that your app is running in is granted only a very limited amount of Memory by the operating system.